# Python get name of class outside of __init__

Tags: python, oop, object

So basically what I'm trying to do is

```
class Object:
    _our_name = type(self).__name__
    __tablename__ = _our_name
    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence(_our_name + '_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
```

but of course I can't use `self` in this case. How would I do this?

Comment: Just `'Object'`.

Comment: Yes, I realize what it's supposed to be. However this is supposed to be an abstract class, which other classes then inherit from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python get class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513019/python-get-class-name)

Comment: "However this is supposed to be an abstract class, which other classes then inherit from" - are you expecting all that `_our_name` stuff to be replaced with the subclass name, for each subclass? It sounds like you'd be better served by a class factory of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. During the class' body execution, the class itself is not yet defined.

You can always create the class and change it later, or create the class using type(...)/metaclasses. But you shouldn't go this route unless you **really** need it.